# How to create a scaffold with differing controller and model names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a versioned JSON API in rails, where the controllers also respond to HTML, meaning it can be accessed as a browser or through an app I'm developing. The controllers have the form Model::V1::UsersController (Model instead of API since they don't just respond to JSON), and I currently have the following in my routes.rb:

```
namespace :model, path: 'm', as: '' do
  # For objects in the model, accessible by JSON (through the app) or HTML (through the browser, using forms to send data to the server).

  scope module: 'v1', constraints: OrConstraint.new([APIConstraint.new(1), APIConstraint.new(:default)]) do
    resources :users do
      collection do
        post :sign_in
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I plan to add more models to my API, but how can I use scaffolding to do this? For example, to create a controller Model::V1::CommentsController, but using the Comment model, instead of Model::V1::Comments.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, and googling for people with similar problems shows that a few people say not to use scaffolding at all in this case: I don't want to do this, as it would mean writing all the views myself, which would be very time-consuming. Apart from that, I can't find much. **nifty-generators** was suggested somewhere, but it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore: no activity since 2012. I'm new to rails, and it might be that I've missed something quite obvious, but I find it surprising that not many others have had the same issue.

I've considered making my own generator, but looking at the source of https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb, it seems very complicated.

EDIT: I've just discovered that I can pass the --model-name parameter to the rails scaffold generator to achieve what I want, but for some reason it still tries to create a model with the same name as the controller. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

I've settled with this solution, by not generating a model at all using the scaffold generator:
To create Model::V1::CommentsController as the controller and Comments as the model:

```
rails g model comment
rails g scaffold model/v1/comments --model-name=comment --no-orm
```